# UTF-16 Encoding and Japanese in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, mojibake

I am trying to encode Japanese characters to UTF-16; basically mimic what this online tool does:  https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter

For example,

```
'インスタントグラム'
```

should become

```
'\u30a4\u30f3\u30b9\u30bf\u30f3\u30c8\u30b0\u30e9\u30e0'
```

I am using the following block of code:

```
jp_example = 'インスタントグラム'
jp_example.encode('utf-16')
```

and instead receive output that looks like this:

```
b'\xff\xfe\xa40\xf30\xb90\xbf0\xf30\xc80\xb00\xe90\xe00'
```

Any idea what I'm missing? I played around with other encodings and nothing has worked for me.

FWIW, I am using a Jupyter Notebook with Python 3.6.3rc1+ .

Comment: Your expected output is not UTF-16. Python produced actual UTF-16 data. Are you trying to produce JSON perhaps?

Comment: The `\xff\xfe` is a Byte Order Mark that specifies that the rest of the string is UTF-16-LE, as opposed to UTF-16-BE. If you don’t want that, you have to pick an endianness and specify it explicitly.

Comment: The rest is exactly what UTF-16-LE looks like when viewed as bytes. For example, the two bytes `\xa4\x30` (aka `\xa40`) mean code unit `0x30a4`, which is how you encode U+30a4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expected output **is not UTF-16**. UTF-16 is an [encoding that uses 2 bytes per codepoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16); `イ`, [Unicode codepoint U+30A4 KATAKANA LETTER I](https://codepoints.net/U+30A4), when represented in UTF-16 bytes as A4 30 or 30 A4 hexadecimal, depending on the [byte order the encoder picked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte_order_encoding_schemes).

Instead, your expected output consists of Unicode codepoints embedded in `\u` escapes. Such escapes are used in multiple contexts, including Python string literals and JSON data.

If you are producing JSON data, use `json.dumps()` to create a JSON string; any codepoints in that string outside of the ASCII character set are represented with `\uhhhh` escape sequences:

```
>>> jp_example = 'インスタントグラム'
>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps(jp_example))
"\u30a4\u30f3\u30b9\u30bf\u30f3\u30c8\u30b0\u30e9\u30e0"
```

Otherwise, if you are generating Python string literals, use the `unicode_escape` codec; this outputs a byte sequence too; for printing purposes I've decoded those bytes to text again using the ASCII codec

```
>>> print(jp_example.encode('unicode_escape').decode('ascii'))
\u30a4\u30f3\u30b9\u30bf\u30f3\u30c8\u30b0\u30e9\u30e0
```

You need to be **absolutely certain** as to what your data is used for. JSON and Python string literal notation differs when it comes to codepoints outside of the [Basic Multi-lingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), such as most Emoji:

```
>>> print(json.dumps(''))
"\ud83d\udc31\ud83d\udc64"
>>> print(''.encode('unicode_escape').decode('ascii'))
\U0001f431\U0001f464
```

JSON uses [surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+10000_to_U+10FFFF) to represent such codepoints, while Python uses a `\Uhhhhhhhh` 8-hex-digit escape sequence.

And just to be explicit: what that unicode-converter site produces is not helpful and outright misleading. The 'UTF-16' box produces JSON-notation escape sequences, or UTF-16 little-endian hex values when you check the *Remove \u* box, without a byte order mark. What the `u+` markup for the UTF-32 output is supposed to do I don't quite understand, and the UTF-8 box outputs a [UTF-8-to-Latin-1 Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). I would not use that site.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I've re-checked the project outline I'm working on, and *yes*, you are absolutely right.

In fact, the json import makes things neater and simpler -- thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @EhRa: JSON documents themselves are Unicode string values, and need to be encoded to a character encoding. The default is UTF-8, but UTF-16 is permitted. When using the default settings, where `json.dumps()` uses ASCII-save `\uhhhh` escape sequences, using UTF-16 is a huge waste of bandwidth, however. If you are setting `ensure_ascii=False` when encoding to JSON, UTF-16 can be a sensible option.